# Error while installing Anaconda due to python_default

Tags: python, windows, installation, anaconda

I started having issues with anaconda when I installed python 3.10 (for another reason), and although I removed the python version 3.10 and reinstalled anaconda it's still not working properly.

I get the following issue during the installation :

> CustomValidationError: Parameter default_python = 'Python 3.10.0' declared in <> is invalid.
> default_python value 'Python 3.10.0' not of the form '[23].[0-9]' or ''

I tried putting a different version of python in my environment variables but it still doesn't work.

Can you please help me out and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have blocked some functions in python
Use this program and it will be OK
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/P5EQ/w2bcrfiyA

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

**That because your anaconda version is less than `4.10.0`, in this version anaconda has a bug for 'Python 3.10'.**

You can see this [context.py](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/4.8.x/conda/base/context.py#L105)
in the line 105:

```py
def default_python_validation(value):
    if value:
        # Here is the bug that len of value can not be great than 3.
        if len(value) == 3 and value[1] == '.':
          # omitted
    else:
        # Set to None or '' meaning no python pinning
        return True

    return "default_python value '%s' not of the form '[23].[0-9]' or ''" % value
```

In this code **your python version's length can not be great than
3, cause your python version is `3.10` so `3.10` is not permit for this case.**

But in the new version of anaconda(`4.10.0`) already fixed, [context.py of new version](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/4.10.3/conda/base/context.py#L105)

#### Solution

##### **1. Solution for avoid reinstall anaconda**

You can just modify the code in the local for solve this bug.

First we need to find out the path to the current conda library.

```sh
echo ~/anaconda3/lib/python*/site-packages/conda-*
```

Here is my path

```sh
/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda-4.11.0-py3.7.egg-info
```

Then for me this location is `/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/base/context.py`

Change the code

```py
if len(value) == 3 and value[1] == '.':
```

To

```py
if len(value) >= 3 and value[1] == '.':
```

##### **2. Solution for prevent this happening in the future**

Update the conda version